# Очистка текстбоксов с TextBox.Changed с помощью кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Работаю в Windows Forms (c#). Есть textbox-ы, при получении данных оттуда, в другой textbox выводится результат расчета, проще говоря автоматический вывод расчета. Пытаюсь сделать кнопку "Очистить все", которая бы очищала все textbox-ы, но при её нажатии очищается часть textbox-ов и выдается ошибка приложения "input string was not in correct format", как я понял кнопка очищает их, но код все равно пытается выполнятся, не получая никаких данных из textbox-ов. Хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать так, что бы кнопка работала, и код условно говоря "переставал" бы принимать данные пока textbox-ы очищаются. Извините если что то не понятно выразил.
Вот код одного из textbox-ов

```
private void speed_kenegry_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double mass, speed;
        mass = Convert.ToDouble(mass_kenegry.Text);
        speed = Convert.ToDouble(speed_kenegry.Text);
        result_kenegry.Text = Convert.ToString(mass * (speed * speed) / 2);
    }
```

Comment: просто сделайте проверку на пустое значение, если пустое - выходите из метода, иначе выполняйте код дальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть методы распознавания чисел, которые не бросают исключений.

И вынесите код в отдельный метод, чтобы не дублировать его в обработчиках.

```cs
private void speed_kenegry_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calculate();
}

private void Calculate()
{
    if (double.TryParse(mass_kenegry.Text, out double mass)
        && double.TryParse(speed_kenegry.Text, out double speed))
    {
        result_kenegry.Text = (mass * (speed * speed) / 2).ToString(); // .ToString("F2"); - 2 знака после запятой
    }
    else
    {
        // этот код выполнится, если не удалось распарсить одно из чисел
    }
}
```

Либо так тоже можно

```cs
private void Calculate()
{
    try
    {
        double mass = double.Parse(mass_kenegry.Text);
        double speed = double.Parse(speed_kenegry.Text);
        result_kenegry.Text = (mass * (speed * speed) / 2).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result_kenegry.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```